# Adding Cordova to ionic 4 failing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have been trying to add Cordova to ionic 4 projects but i keep getting an error and I know prior now i was able to add the same but not anymore.

Whenever i run the below command its exiting with error code 1

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing`

[image]
[image]
I don't actually know what i am doing wrong or Cordova is no longer working

I have asked in the ionic forum but no response yet

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/not-able-to-add-cordova-to-ionic-4/177323

Comment: Do you have 'c:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe' in your path environnement variable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1178674/wmic-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: No @Sam I will add it and see how it goes

Comment: @Sam issue was sorted after adding `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`  to my env. variables then restarting the PC. Thanks